# How can I disable SIP on IOS 12.x

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12, cisco-commands, voip, sip

How would I disable SIP on an Cisco router running IOS 12.x?

Comment: Both Darren and Brett have answered below however it would be better to be a little clearer what you mean with future questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on which version of 12.x you're on, you should be able to do the following:

```
router(config)#sip-ua
router(config-sip-ua)#no transport tcp
router(config-sip-ua)#no transport udp
```

This stops the router from listening on port 5060.

Comment: There's also TLS. Cisco actually has this documented in a security bulletin. To be **absolutely** sure, include an acl on internet (insecure) links.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean how to disable the SIP ALG you can configure the following:

```
no ip nat service sip udp port 5060
```